# What kind of SSD is compatible for MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd

I'm about to buy SSD for my Macbook Pro mid 2010. What would you recommend for the following specification:

MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)
Processor: 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
Memory: 4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

Comment: any will do, but be aware that if you plan to run Yosemite, it will make you problems if it is not a Apple disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer do I need adaptor or extension? Or it is fit with the slot?

Comment: Fit in the slot is all it needs.

Comment: How about the maximum capacity of the SSD? Which brand you would suggest?

Comment: That is mainly depending on your budget, take look here http://www.mac-upgrade-store.com/collections/macbook-pro-13-inch-mid-2010/products/solid-state-drive?variant=864933881&gclid=CjwKEAjwmfKpBRC8tb3Mh5rs23ASJACWy1QPS9GLRFFIaBl0_BmLC8hXt-EM8j1eqi-sdYbZMbqaNRoCaOvw_wcB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any SSD in a 2.5 inch form factor package will work. Pre-2013 models used standard drives, after that they went ssd-only.